# Axios failing to downloand an image from s3 due to CORS

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, amazon-s3, cors, axios

When making Axios GET call to retrieve an image from s3 bucket it creates a preflight check using OPTIONS method. Options method response includes the `Access-Controll-Allow-Origin: *` header with a wild card but the subsequent GET call fails to retrieve the image.

Browser console out put:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Response headers from the OPTIONS call:
[image: Response headers from the OPTIONS call]

Response headers from the subsequent GET call:

[image: Response headers from the subsequent GET call:]

Axios config for the GET call:

[image: Axios config for the GET call:]

Answer (score 0):

Go to bucket permission and configure cors [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html][s3 cors documentation]

[image]